Evaluate the derivative of the integral to get the specific form
$$
\frac{d}{dt}{\alpha}\left(t\right)=\frac{d}{dt}\left[2 \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{x \sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}}-\pi\right]
$$
$$
       =\frac{3-2 t}{t{ }^2\left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)} \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{(4 x-3) d x}{(3-2 x)^2 x \sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}} 
$$
I have applied the Leibniz rule for differentiating an integral. However, the result I get is not in the form given above. The result I get is
$$
\frac{1}{t^2\left(1-\frac{2}{t}\right)} \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{t\left[\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]} \frac{d x}{x \sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}}
$$

Welcome to the Mathematics StackExchange!  You'll get a better answer if you explain the context for your question (why are you expecting this answer?), and what you've already tried (what did you get instead?); see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/ for more specific advice on writing questions.

I used the Leibniz rule link . The function alpha when integrated with respect to t is expected to be in the given form because it is mentioned in a paper on GTR. However, it is not an expression that is present in any textbooks(browsed through ~20 textbooks). And the authors have not provided any appendix.

I know Leibniz rule, but the hypothesis don't seem to be satisfied here. So, could you please edit again your post, to include the details of your calculations? (I have no clue to answer your question.)

Hi @AnneBauval I simply did a partial derivative of the integrand wrt t keeping x as constant. And as t is one of the limits I took that into account as well in the term f(x,a(t))*d/dt (a(t)) where a(t) in this case is t itself. By the way I applied Leibniz rule because it seemed applicable here. I am attaching the paper here. Eqn 11 differentiated wrt x_o is supposed to yield eqn 15. Could you please give it a look and let me know that Leibniz rule is applicable here. Because that is what I worked with and it would take considerable time to TeX them.

The integral in your (own) result is divergent. And Leibniz is not applicable here because the (original) integrand itself has no (finite) limit as $x\to t$.

Could you please take a look at the paper(just the portion regarding deriving eqn 15 from eqn 11) and suggest how to proceed with the problem? Any reference to calculus books or resources that deal with similar problems would also be a tremendous help. I can work with those pointers and try to get the desired result.

Do you understand my comments about your misuse of Leibniz rule? However, as told before, I have no clue to answer your question. I just looked at the paper but it didn't help.

Yeah I think I got you. The integrand blows up at x=t with 1/0. Right?

Right, so the part $-f(t,t)$ (which should appear from Leibniz rule but which you didn't write) is $\infty$. Moreover, the other part (the integral $\int_t^\infty\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}f(t,x)dx$ you wrote) is divergent.

If the integration variable $t$ and the lower bound are really the same and not a lapsus by blind formula copy, the derivative is the the sum of both partial derivatives, one wrt to the lower bound yielding minus the value of the integrand at the lower bound, and the integral of the derivative.
$$\partial_t \int_t^{\infty } f(t,x) \ dx =  \int_t^{\infty } \partial_t f (t,x) \, dx-f(t,t)$$
By the linearity of d, the rule comes from the total differerential of a function of several variables, with some of of them identified.
Rule by thumb, differentiate each single occurence of $t$ in the formula and add the results.

The integration variable is x and the integral is being differentiated wrt t

Thats not the question. Its a not so common case, that the outer lower bound of the integral $t$ occurs inside the integrand.

It is quite common (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). Anyway, this answer doesn't even make sense. $\alpha'(t)$ should (like $\alpha(t)$) depend only on the unique variable, namely $t$. The integration variable $x$ is a dummy variable. Moreover, writing someting like $\int_t^{\infty }\dots , dt$ is a (sadly frequent) beginner's mistake.
